# Appending one list to another to combine data sources

Tags: excel, vba

So I have several tables on different sheets

**Sheet 1**

A...B

Allan...345

Angela...500

**Sheet 2**

A...B

Brian...600

Brenda...250

**Sheet 3**

A...B

Colin...190

Cathy...370

I would like the data on all three sheets to be appended to each other on sheet 4 as follows:

A...B

Allan...345

Angela...500

Brian...600

Brenda...250

Colin...190

Cathy...370

Ideally any changes made to sheets 1-3 or additional rows inserted into those tables are inserted automatically on **sheet 4** so that the combined list is always up to date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://superuser.com/questions/537339/how-do-i-merge-two-tables-in-excel-that-have-identical-columns

Comment: And the question is? Friendly reminder: StackOverflow is not a "we code for you" service provider. [Introduction to VBA](https://blog.udemy.com/excel-macros-tutorial/).I'm surprised though, your reputation indicate that you know this already.

Comment: I was looking for a bit of guidance although a solution was welcome if one was forthcoming.

Comment: You can use the `Worksheet_Change` event to trigger the update.

Comment: I answered my own question and am quite happy to share despite the pointless downvoting and petition to close the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After defining a name for each column of data on each sheet A through C, as per this [convention](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4D0F13AC-53B7-422E-AFD2-ABD7FF379C64), I was able to produce the desired output using

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(ListX,ROWS(A1:$A$1)),IFERROR(INDEX(ListY,ROWS(A1:$A$1)-ROWS(ListX)),IFERROR(INDEX(ListZ,ROWS(A1:$A$1)-ROWS(ListX)-ROWS(ListY))"")))
```

using SHIFT+CTRL+ENTER to create the formula as an array function and by copying down I was able to automatically list the entire contents of both columns separately.

Additional information about defined name is [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DefinedNames.aspx), which was new to me.